# Python: How to index the elements of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm looking for a function that would do what the function `indices` does in the following hypothetical code:

```
indices( numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]) )
```

> {1: [(0,0)], 2: [(0,1),(1,0)], 3: [(0,2),(1,1)], 4: [(1,2)]}

Specifically, I want to produce a dictionary whose keys are the unique elements in the flattened array and whose values are lists of the full indices of the respective key.

I've looked at the `where` function, but it does not seem to provide an efficient way to solve this for large arrays. What's the best way to do this?

Notes: I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your desired output is a dictionary, I don't think there's going to be an efficient way to do this with NumPy operations. Your best bet will probably be something like

```
import collections
import itertools

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for indices in itertools.product(*map(range, a.shape)):
    d[a[indices]].append(indices)
```

Comment: I had to change `itertools.product(a.shape)` into `itertools.product(*map(range, a.shape))`, but otherwise this seems to work; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package can perform these kind of grouping operations in an efficient and fully vectorized manner, ie:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
keys, values = npi.group_by(a.reshape(-1), np.indices(a.shape).reshape(-1, a.ndim))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about numpy, but this is an example solution if just using arrays:

```
arrs = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
dict = {}

for i in range(0, len(arrs)):
    arr = arrs[i]
    for j in range(0, len(arr)):
        num = arr[j]
        indices = dict.get(num)
        if indices is None:
            dict[num] = [(i, j)]
        else:
            dict[num].append((i, j))
```

Comment: This is nice, but I suspect that it's less performant than the solution by user2357112; more importantly, though, this won't work for arrays of arbitrary depth, such as `[[[0], [5]], [[10], [15]], [[20], [25]]]`. These are supported by numpy, so I'd like to include them.